# Transferring columns to a new df with exploded cells and repeated title name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of **journal title** and **era_subject** (discipline of that journal) that is not tidy, containing multiple values in the same cell of the `era_subjects` Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'title':['Veterinary pathology', 'Clothing and textiles research journal'],
'era_subjects':["[['07', 'Agricultural and Veterinary Sciences'], ['04', 'Fisheries Sciences'], ['0707', 'Veterinary Sciences']]","[['1203', 'Design Practice and Management'], ['12', 'Built Environment and Design']]"],
'cpu_rank': ['1', '2'],
'subscribed': ['True', 'False'],
'downloads': ['800', '550']})
```

[image: df with multiple values in Series era_subjects]

I wrote a function to extract and return only the broadest-level, two-digit subject strings from `era_subjects` (there can be multiple).  The result of my function on `row 0` for example is a cell containing:

```
['Agricultural and Veterinary Sciences', 'Fisheries Sciences']
```

I then used the technique outlined in the Medium article [here](https://sureshssarda.medium.com/pandas-splitting-exploding-a-column-into-multiple-rows-b1b1d59ea12e) to explode that resulting cell into a **new_df** having multiple rows with the journal name repeated when necessary:

[image: df with columns title and era_split. values in column title are repeated]

Now, I want to supplement this **new_df** with information from the original **df**, such as `subscribed` for a journal title.  I can't use **new_df** `title` as the index to look up since it's repeated (rows 0 and 1, for example).

After a lot of trial and error, and a walk down a dead end for the `join` and `merge` methods which I couldn't figure out, I've done this:

```
for i in df.set_index('title').index:
    temp_sub = df.set_index('title').loc[i, 'subscribed']
    
    temp_filt = (new_df['title'] == i)
    new_df.loc[temp_filt, 'subscribed'] = temp_sub
```

Use title in the original **df** (which will be unique for each row) to hold the subscribed status of that title, then filter the **new_df** on that title and set the subscribed status.

Questions:

1. I'm sure there is a better way to do this. How else could I have
   done it?
2. `subscribed` is one of seven or so columns I want to bring over
   from the original **df** based on the journal title.  Can I do that efficiently, or do I have
   to do seven separate temp variables and assignments?

### Edit: Adding desired final new_df

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
'title':['Veterinary pathology', 'Veterinary pathology', 'Clothing and textiles research journal'],
'era_subjects':["Agricultural and Veterinary Sciences", 'Fisheries Sciences', 'Built Environment and Design'],
'cpu_rank': ['1', '1', '2'],
'subscribed': ['True', 'True', 'False'],
'downloads': ['800', '800', '550']})
```

[image]

Comment: can  you not join df and new_df on title?, and while joining filter the columns that you want

Comment: `new_df.join(df, how='left', on='title', lsuffix='_newdf', rsuffix='_df')` gives me an error: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: can you also post as addendum in question, the final dataframe new_df ?

Comment: Added to the question now

Comment: Also, a deleted (?) answer suggested using `df.explode()`.  Reading the documentation seems like it would work here, but running `df.explode('era_split')` (when `era_split` is a list of the broad, two-digit subject headings) just returns the same df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using `.explode`

`df['era_split']` after my function looks like `"Agricultural and Veterinary Sciences', 'Fisheries Sciences"`

```
df['era_split_by_quotecommaquote'] = df['era_split'].str.split('\', \'')
df2 = df.explode('era_split_by_quotecommaquote')    #new df defined with more rows than the original
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[image]